# Computing the sum of two variables in make file not working

Tags: makefile

```
     a=10
     b=10

b:
  sum=($a+$b)
  @echo hello
  @echo @sum
```

I would like to write a makefile that calculats the sum of two variables but it is not working: may I know the where i made the mistake?

How the make file is executed and what is the default target?

Can I change the default target name in makefile?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use shell syntax for this.  Make does not provide any mathematical functions, itself.  Also note that each logical line in a make recipe is run in a separate shell, which means if you assign a value in one line and use it in the next line, the value will be lost (since the shell where the value was set exits and a new one is started).

So, do something like this:

```
a = 10
b = 10

b:
        @sum=`expr $(a) + $(b)`; echo $$sum
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, makefile run the first target. To run a specific target, you can enter the name of the target you want in commandline like this: `make <targetname>`.

Here is an example of makefile

```
a=10
b=10
sum=$(shell expr $(1) + $(2))

compute_sum:
    @echo $(a)+$(b)=$(call sum,$(a),$(b))
    @echo $(sum_a_b)
```

It defines a function `sum`to comput the sum of the 2 arguments. Note that the space around the `+` sign are required.

The default target is `compute_sum` and it calls the function `sum` with `$(call sum,<arg1>,<arg2>)`.

.

Of course, you can use the sum as a variable directly whithout a function:

```
a=10
b=10
sum=$(shell expr $(a) + $(b))
```

Comment: Why so complicated? `sum = $(shell expr $(a) + $(b))` saves a complete fork to a shell for an echo.

Comment: @Jens: Strangely, this does work. I was not working before... Don't know what happened :) Thanks for the tip!